# How to run a cron job in codeigniter without using wget?

Tags: php, cron

I want to run a cron job without using wget in CodeIgniter.
I am using it like this:

```
*/1 * * * * wget  http://assurance.com/controller/function
```

It works successfully, but I do not want to use wget.

Is there any another way to run this CodeIgniter script?

Comment: `*/1` means every minute, which can be achieved with `*` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use something like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php  /pathToTheApp/controller/function
```

But of course the `/usr/bin/php` should be your path to the PHP binaries and `pathToTheApp` should be the **absolute** path to your CI application.

Comment: Codeigniter have .../application/controllers folders, not it's just controller folder as you mention

Answer (score 0):

If you have local shell access on the host, add it to your crontab there.

Comment: Now am using /usr/bin/curl to run the script

Comment: Not sure how that's an improvement, but good for you. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there any problem using this?

Comment: wget is just downloading file on the server. Thats why am not used wget

Comment: if you have a problem with wget downloading the file and making copies of the downloaded file (file(1), file(2), etc..), then just use the `-O outputFile.txt` flag of `wget` and it will always save in this particular `outputFile.txt` overwriting it.

Comment: Or use `/dev/null` as your output file.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this exact thing recently and couldn't find a complete solution. So I'll try to provide one here.

I used "bash shell" because I wanted to make a command line (CLI) call to my controller into of an http (note: I'm using an ubuntu/linux server.

There are three main parts:

The cron call

The shell script

The controller function

---

Cron:

in your server cli type this to access crontab: crontab -e

then add your cron call: `* * * * * bash /path/to/script/test.sh`

(note: I created a folder in my site root called cron, so my path would be:

/var/www/website/cron/test.sh

---

Shell script:

In that cron folder we made, create a file called " test.sh "

In the file put:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/site
/usr/bin/php index.php controller function
```

That's it

cron sets up the timer to call the file
shell calls the controller from the CLI

you'll now be able to use $this->input->is_cli_request() in your function for added security.

```
public function cronTest()
{
    if($this->input->is_cli_request())
    {
        //code goes here;
    }        
}
```

Hope this helps save you some time, this took me way longer than expected :)